# Append URL Query Strings to request

Tags: restsharp

I'm trying to send a `POST` request and format the query string in a specific format. Order doesn't matter aside from the first parameter, but I haven't been successful.

What I need:

> localhost/someapp/api/dosomething/`5335?save=false&userid=66462`

What some of my attempts have spit out:

> http://localhost/someapp/api/dosomething/?Id=29455&save=false&userId=797979
>   http://localhost/someapp/api/dosomething/?save=false&userId=797979

How I formatted the request:

```
    request.AddQueryParameter("Id", "29455");
    request.AddQueryParameter("save", "false");
    request.AddQueryParameter("user", "4563533245");
```

If I try `AddParameter`for `Id` it doesn't get appended on the query string (I'm thinking because it's a POST and not a GET), so that won't work. The API isn't expecting a form, it's expecting :

`(string id, List<Dictionary<string,string>>)`

I could use a `StringBuilder`, but that feels wrong. I'm not sure if `UrlSegment` is the best way to go either, since I would basically be hacking the query string. Is there a way to format my request in the format I need using RestSharp's API?

Comment: You might like [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/)'s approach to building (and calling) URLs. It's quite a bit less verbose than RestSharp. [disclaimer: I'm the author]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I ended up using is `UrlSegment` and then kept the `.AddQueryParameter` methods, so the final code block looks like :

```
var url = new RestClient(localhost/someapp/api/dosomething/{id});
var request     = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("Id", "5335", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddQueryParameter("save", "true");
request.AddQueryParameter("UserId", "5355234");
```

Which produced the URI I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest coding process for using RestSharp or any other API client library would be to use Postman to generate if you are unsure of how to code it. Download Postman, do a new request, enter the URL string to send to the API, click on Code, select C# (RestSharp) from the dropdown. Here is the code it generated.

```
   var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/someapp/api/dosomething   /5335?save=false&userid=66462");
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
   request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "bd05aa45-f1b9-4665-a3e7-888ad16f2800");  
   request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: The AddQueryParameter API exists for a reason though

Comment: Yes, I think the AddQueryParameter is clearer and easier to code than using a long string like Postman generated. But if you are in a pinch and don't have time to research then Postman will give you a quick solution.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the answer